# Is it safe to charge a device with only slightly different voltage and amperage?

Tags: usb, battery-charging, usb-device

My Asus tablet charger has 5.2V and 1.25A.

But my new Micromax phone's charger has 5.0V and 2A.

I am tired of carrying two different chargers everywhere. Is it OK to use either charger to charge both the devices? Both are android devices and both chargers are Micro USB.

Comment: It's always recommended to use original chargers. But, *only output voltage and maximum output current ratings are OK for your case*. You can use but care must be taken because I don't have any info about their protections. Anyway, the second rating of the chargers (1.25A and 2A, respectively) tells you the maximum output current capability of the charger. For example, if your tablet or smartphone draws 0.7A during charging then both of the chargers are able to provide that level of current. But, if another device draws, say, 1.5A then your Asus tablet charger probably will not be suitable.

Comment: you can use the phone charger on both.